# Pandas create column with the maximum value based on duplicate values from another column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Hi all I have this dataframe. I am trying to create 2 additional columns, max_temperature and min_temperature to record the maximum and minimum temperature values based on the stayid. How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try groupby, agg and pd.join

```
  newdf=(df.set_index('stayid')#Set stayid to allow joining of the aggregated to the main df
    .join(# This joins the ggregated df to main df
        df.groupby('stayid')['temp'].agg([min,max])# Compute the min and max temperature and put them into a summarised df
    ).rename(columns={'min':'min_temp', 'max':'max_temp'}))#rename the min and max columns)
```